# js regex to match path that starts with X and then not Y

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match

```
/.well-known/*
```

Except

```
/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

I've tried a few things around

```
\/\.well-known\/^(?!apple-app-site-association).*
```

but they don't match strings like

```
/.well-known/123/erg3rg
/.well-known/
```

:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/\/\.well-known\/^(?!apple-app-site-association).*/)
"/.well-known/apple-app-site-association".match(reg) // null :)
"/.well-known/123".match(reg) // null :(
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you have an extraneous `^`. It should be:

`\/\.well-known\/(?!apple-app-site-association)`

The caret is to match the beginning of the text, so it will never match in the middle of your regex.

**Note:** the `.*` at the end was also extraneous, since it would match all the same with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
  \/\.well-known\/(?!apple-app-site-association).*
```

I just removed the ^.